# Prove the identity $\cos(2x)\csc^{2}(x)=2\cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Could you help me to prove this identity $\cos(2x)\csc^{2}(x)=2\cos(2x)$

I can only get $$\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=2(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))$$

How do I proceed from there?

Comment: either you are typesetting wrong or  the equation is not true in general you can cancel out cos(2x) from both side it becomes $\csc^2x=2$

Comment: The identity, if you divide both sides by $\cos(2x)$, is basically saying that $\csc ^2x = 2$.

Comment: I also suspect that this equation is problematic. If it is about solving this equation then it makes more sense. This is from a question from my past test.

Comment: Or $\cos(2x)=0$

Comment: Your cosecant needs an argument, both in the title and in the body of the question.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Fix the equation or close the question.

Answer (score 1):

The identity $\cos(2x)\csc^2x = 2\cos(2x)$ is false.  If $x = 0$, the left-hand side is undefined, but the right-hand side is equal to $2$.